# JPA Hibernate Update query in interface

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

The goal is to update entries in a table. Conceptually I need...

```java
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Message set isRead = true where receiver = id and isRead = false")
    void markAllAsRead(Long id);
```

This compiles however when I run it It seems as though the transaction never commits. According to the documentation I need to flush the cache. This doesn't seem possible with my current setup with what Ive seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328935/problem-with-entity-update-with-jpa-hibernate) because I do not have a function body. I'm trying to fix someone elses' code so I really don't want to refactor the entire thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the following parameter?

```
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
```